# Suppressing hiding details when zooming out in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way how to suppress hiding (some) details when zooming out in Google Maps?

For instance, I want to suppress hiding of the feature type `transit.line`, which is hidden on zoom level 10 and less. Is it possible, for example, by overriding [events](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html) attached to `zoom_changed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, there isn't a way to do it.

[Styled maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html) allow you to specify which layers are available on the map. Google split out the original png bitmaps isolating each component (such as transit lines), with the rest of the png transparent. The problem here is that components that are not in the combined png will also not be available in the separated out pngs.

Playing around with the [Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and chrome dev tools shows that even if you specify transit lines be viewed at zoom levels < 10, the pngs that google gives you just don't have the images you want.